# Enity id and EJB Services security

Tags: jpa, ejb

In many cases EJB services deliver enities from the database red per JPA. 
For example read a customer address do some changes and save it via the EJB address service again in the database (em.merge). So if the EJB service is statless (and i think all of you would do it stateless) there is a security problem, because the client can change the address id and alter another address. Is there a pattern for this problem or any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement the concept of permissions in your system.

You first need to define what are the rules that determine who can change the address (e.g. an address can only be modified by users who live in the city that address belongs to) and then implement it in your business layer. I think your question's answer can be as complex as your business rules are.

Going back to the example that you provide, if a customer modifies a random id as you suggest, it would be of little benefit as ids are usually auto generated, but of course you need to take care of those aspects in your app.